# Subprocess does not give output with Flow

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to call [facebook/flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) commands from a python script. It does not give the expected `result`. The `result` variable is `(b'', None)`.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/flow", "--help"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate()    
print(result)
```

I have flow installed on my Mac OS X Yosemite, and executable exist on the used directory. I also have `R` installed and when I use below code it produces a valid output `( b'b'\nUsage: R [options] [< infile] [> outfile]\n', None)`.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/R", "--help"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate()    
print(result)
```

Why isn't `subprocess` fail only for [flow](http://flowtype.org)? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Using below code it produces the expected output,

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/flow", "--help"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate()    
print(result)
```

Any clarifications for this behaviour?

Comment: what output do you get when you run `flow` from command line? Did you try PIPING stderr , maybe there is some data in stderr?

Comment: `flow --help` produces `Usage: flow [COMMAND] 

Valid values for COMMAND:
  autocomplete    Queries autocompletion ...` on the terminal

Comment: Try redirecting `stderr` to `subprocess.PIPE` and then check if that has what you want

Comment: @AnandSKumar I tried your suggestion! It works! Any insights? :)

Comment: The process is writing its output to stderr, not stdout that is why you only get when you pipe stderr , I would also suggest that you pipe in both stdout as well as stderr , sometimes other useful info can go into stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, when you execute the command -

```
/usr/local/bin/flow --help
```

The process is writing its output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Hence, you would only get the output when you also PIPE the stderr output. Example -

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/flow", "--help"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This would pipe in both stdout as well as stderr, and then you can use the output you require.

`Popen.communicate()` returns a tuple of the format - `(stdout, stderr)` - so the second element in the tuple would be having the data you require.